# On constructive calculus of variations

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, calculus-of-variations, constructive-mathematics

I am looking for a constructive treatment of calculus of variations and, a bit more generally, infinite-dimensional vector spaces. To a certain extent, my problem is that I am not sure what the right keywords for a search are.

Comment: What do you understand under 'constructive'?

Comment: CoV is kinda like a rabbit hole - it is best to state your specific problem/context and then ask for literature on this topic.

Comment: @daw I mean without law of excluded middle.

Comment: @F.Conrad I was thinking about Euler-Lagrange equations.